# Not able to call a function using document.getElementById('password').addEventListener() with a webpack & ES6 setup

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, addeventlistener, es6-class

I am using **webpack** & **ES6 classes**. I am trying to call '**onblur**' function on input#password but its not working. It neither throws any error nor it calls the callback function. If I try and find input#password outside eventListener using console.log(document.getElementById('password')) then it gives me the input#password as a DOM object. I don't know where I am going wrong with this. Below is my code:

index.html

```
    <head>
      <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Please enter your password" autofocus="autofocus">
    </body>
```

webpack-config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
    }
};
```

index.js

```
import { Password } from './app/main';

document.getElementById('password').addEventListener('onblur', () => {
    console.log('im here');
    var initPwd = new Password();
    initPwd.init();
})
```

main.js

```
class Password {
    init() {
        console.log('I am inside init.')
    }
}

export { Password }
```

Please help!

Answer (score 4):

```
document.getElementById('password').addEventListener('onblur', () => {
```

=>

```
document.getElementById('password').addEventListener('blur', () => {
```

`onblur` would work with `element.onblur = function() {}`, so when you using `addEventListener` interface you should not write `on` in the event name.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the *event name* is `blur`, while you can assign handlers by assigning to the `onblur` property of the element. They're not the same, which can be a bit confusing.

When you attach a listener by assigning to a property, you use `<element>.on<eventName>` syntax, eg:

```
element.onclick = () => ...
element.onblur = () => ...
```

When you use `addEventListener`, you just use the plain event name:

```
element.addEventListener('click', () => ...
element.addEventListener('blur', () => ...
```

So, change to:

```
document.getElementById('password').addEventListener('blur', () => {
```

```js
document.getElementById('password').addEventListener('blur', () => {
  console.log('blur');
});
```

```html
<input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Please enter your password" autofocus="autofocus">
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, consider upvoting and marking it as Accepted to indicate that the issue is resolved :)